# Simplify treats a solution differently when it's formatted as an equation instead of a rule

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Solutions returned by Solve are provided as rules:

```
solnRule1 = 
  y -> 1/(3 (1 + x)) - (-1 + 2 x)/(6 (1 - x + x^2)) + 2/(
    3 (1 + 1/3 (-1 + 2 x)^2));
```

Solutions returned by Reduce are provided as equations:

```
solnEqn1 = 
  y == 1/(3 (1 + x)) - (-1 + 2 x)/(6 (1 - x + x^2)) + 2/(
    3 (1 + 1/3 (-1 + 2 x)^2));
```

It has been my experience that Simplify treats both of these the same:

```
Simplify@solnRule1
Simplify@solnEqn1
```

[image]

However, that is not the case for these identical solutions:

```
 solnRule2 = 
  y -> -((-10 cF Ee F Log[10] + 10 cF Epzc F Log[10] - 
     23 cF pH R T Log[10] + 23 cF pKa R T Log[10] + 
     23 cF R T Log[f/(1 - f)])/(10 F Log[10]));
 solnEqn2 = 
  y == -((-10 cF Ee F Log[10] + 10 cF Epzc F Log[10] - 
     23 cF pH R T Log[10] + 23 cF pKa R T Log[10] + 
     23 cF R T Log[f/(1 - f)])/(10 F Log[10]));
```

When Simplify is applied to the rule-based version of the above solution, it acts normally:

```
Simplify@solnRule2
```

[image]

But when Simplify is applied to the equation-based version, it equates the solution to zero:

```
Simplify@solnEqn2
```

[image]

I don't know why Simplify is doing this.  When I convert solnEqn2 to a rule-based format, it behaves normally:

```
ToRules@solnEqn2
Simplify@%
```

[image]

This can cause problems when applying Simplify to the output of Reduce:  Reduce can provide solutions to several different variables, and when one solution is equated to zero it can be difficult to determine the variable it represents.

I'm using:

[image]

Comment: I get the `Solve` solution, plus a couple of other cases, with `Reduce` in V12.2.

Comment: @MichaelE2  That's odd, because I'm also using V12.2 (on MacOS 10.13.6); I just added a screenshot indicating this.  And I reconfirmed the behavior by quitting/reopening MMA and then pasting directly from my post.  Are you using MMA for Windows or Linux and, if so, might that account for the difference?  OTOH, if you're on a Mac, I should try re-downloading and reinstalling the program.

Comment: I'm on a Mac (11.3.1). This is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5BQg.png -- The third solution (third part of the `Or`) is equivalent to the `Solve` solution. Uh-oh, I just tried applying `Simplify` and the `Solve` solution disappears.  I guess that explains the diff.  It may be a bug (in `Solve` perhaps); but it's quite late here, and I don't want to try to figure that out right now.  Or perhaps `Simplify` does a generically correct transformation that erroneously eliminates the solution.

Comment: @MichaelE2   I see the same thing. [Though I think what you meant to say was "I just tried applying `Simplify` and the `Reduce` solution disappears" -- as you said, it's currently late where you are :).]   Since you identified the problem as resulting not from Reduce by itself, but rather from the application of Simplify to Reduce's solution, I rewrote my question.

Comment: It was late and maybe I didn't look closely enough. These give the same result: `Solve[Simplify[red], \[Sigma]M]` and `Solve[sys, \[Sigma]M, {Vs, VF}]`, where `sys` is the system in the first `Reduce`.

Comment: That's interesting.  Are you just mentioning this as one more aspect of the curious behavior: That even though the solution for $\sigma \mathrm M$ is equated to zero in `Simplify[red]`, `Solve` recovers the link between the solution and $\sigma \mathrm M$ using `Solve[Simplify[red], M]`?  Or are you saying this explains why Simplify is equating Reduce's solution for $\sigma \mathrm M$ to zero?  [If it's the latter, I'm missing it.]

Comment: @MichaelE2  I've honed in on what's going on, which has enabled a significant simplification (no pun intended) in my post.  Essentially, it seems to have nothing to do with either `Solve` or `Reduce`, but instead turns on a difference between how `Simplify` handles this particular solution when it is provided in an equation-based rather than rule-based format.  I've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple explanation for this (thanks to WRI tech support for pointing this out).

When Simplify acts on Simplify@solnEqn2, it's acting on the equation as a whole, rather just on the RHS of the expression (the latter is what Simplify does when the solution is expressed as a rule), to put the equation into what its algorithm determines is the simplest form.

What I missed is that, in so doing, in this particular case, Simplify inserted the variable (f) into the equation itself, to obtain an expression that equals zero.  This can be seen more clearly if we use a more distinctive variable (XXXX):

```
solnEqn2A = 
  XXXX == -((-10 cF Ee F Log[10] + 10 cF Epzc F Log[10] - 
        23 cF pH R T Log[10] + 23 cF pKa R T Log[10] + 
        23 cF R T Log[f/(1 - f)])/(10 F Log[10]))
Simplify@solnEqn2A
```

[image]

The take-home message is that, if you ask Reduce to isolate specific variables, that isolation may be lost if you apply Simplify to Reduce's output. [Or, more generally, that variable isolation can be lost anytime a solution is in equation form.] One solution is to use ToRules before applying Simplify.